# Pandas : Data Frame Pruning

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as given below:

```
data = [['1','tom',1,0],['1','tom',0,1],['2','lynda',0,1],['2','lynda',0,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','NAME', 'A','B'])

df.head()
```

[image: DataFrame Snapshot]

I want to transform the dataframe to look like the below:
where in logical OR is taken for columns A and B. ID and NAME will always have same pair-values irrespective of how many times they appear but columns A and B can change(00,10,11,01).

So at the end I want ID,NAME,A,B.
[image: Transformed Dataframe]

Comment: `df.groupby(['ID','NAME'],as_index=False).max()
`

Answer (score 1):

You can always sum and compare to 0.

```
data = [['1','tom',1,0],['1','tom',0,1],['2','lynda',0,1],['2','lynda',0,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','NAME', 'A','B'])

g_df = (df.groupby(['ID', 'NAME']).sum() >0).astype(float)

g_df.reset_index()
```